# Area 51: Influence of increasing reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, area-51, commitment

When my overall reputation (through all projects) is growing, does it have an increasing influence on the commitment level of the projects I commited to, or is only taken in account the reputation level at the moment I commited?

Comment: I believe it's recalculated everyday when they resync the global reputation you have, I think a dev could confirm that. And sorry for the false alert answer, I misread the question.

Comment: I hope a developer will someday look around...